# Restart system in the deployment of visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I there any option to restart in the visual studio when my product install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is something that the installer can do - and the install projects in visual studio are exactly one thing: crap. Get yourself a copy of WIX (look it up - it is on sourceforge) and use that. This is the "official" upgrade - it is also used to make the Visual Studio installer. There you can do EVERYTHING that the installer can do.

Comment: I have install WIX, can you kindly give me some hints how to use it.